# Re-Installing debug application with conflicting provider

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I have an issue when attempting to test my application directly from Android Studio. I have an application that implements a provider in its manifest, however whenever I run the application on my device from AS I get the following error.

[image: Android Studio Error]

This is fine, I understand the error, and I do not mind uninstalling the application every time before I re-test it. The problem I have is that even after I uninstall the application (either manually or through the dialog option) and I try to re-run the application the same dialog still appears and I am unable to install it.

The only solution seems to be to uninstall the application and restart the device, which is obviously an annoying process. If anyone has faced this issue and solved it without having to restart the phone each time or change the authorities each time I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

**Update:**

My Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app.testing">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>                
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".services.SyncContacts"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/sync_server_info" />
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name=".providers.Contacts"
        android:label="Contacts Provider"
        android:authorities="@string/appAuthority"
        android:exported="true"
        android:syncable="true"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

And my sync resource file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="@string/appAuthority"
    android:accountType="@string/account"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I had a related problem concerning the sync adapter and changing between release and debug versions of the app.  I'm not sure if this will give you any clues about your problem, but figured it wouldn't hurt to post it here.

As with your manifest, I also had the sync adapter running in the ':sync' process, but only in release.

For debug builds I had a snippet in gradle like this:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (buildType == "debug") {
        variant.resValue "string", "sync_process", variant.applicationId
    }
}
```

... and then using the string resource in the manifest.  This would ensure that in debug builds the sync adapter would run on the main thread and would be easy to breakpoint.

The other part of the problem is that I was using the same content provider on both release and debug, but with two different applicationIds.

When I tried to install a release build to test the ':sync' process on my own device, I'd get the conflicting provider message.  Uninstalling the app in any manner didn't seem to remove it completely, nor a further reboot, and yet it did not show up in settings.  So I ended up forcing debug to use the ':sync' process.

Finally I solved the problem by building debug again with all processes running on the main thread (i.e. the above snippet enabled).  I then changed the provider to explicitly have another name.  I then ran the build in Android Studio.

After this the content provider was changed.  I now made the application id consistent between debug and release, causing the content provider/application id conflict to not be a problem.

The relation between my problem and yours seems to be having parts of the app on different processes (in particular the sync adapter) and then trying to uninstall builds.  It appears that the Android OS is retaining some state of the application of such builds after deletion.